# apache2 ldap authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, mod-auth-ldap

For whatever reason, I am not able to include the following line in my httpd.conf:

```
AuthBasicProvider file ldap
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Unknown Authn provider: ldap
```

Apache is compiled from source with :

```
--enable-authnz-ldap 
--enable-ldap
```

What other compile-time options should I pass?  Building this for svn/ldap servers, compiling support in instead of dso.

Thanks!
V

Answer (score 1):

Must add --with-ldap to compile options

Answer (score 1):

If ldap is compiled as a module, have you enabled it in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: This will be it. If the module isn't enabled its directives won't be recognized.